# How can i Display product item 1 by 1 by clicking a product ? i already call the id of the product but i cant display the whole data of product

Tags: reactjs

I already call the id of the product but I can't display the whole data of product, for example, name, stock, and image

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-xl-4">
  {products.items.map(item => (
    <div className="col mb-sm-3" key={item._id}>
      <div className="card product-card-single mb-sm-3 h-100">
        <img
          src="https://via.placeholder.com/198x144"
          className="card-img-top"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">
            <Link to={"Product-page/ProductPage/" + item._id}>{item.name}</Link>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div className="card-footer">
          <p className="card-text price mb-1">
            <strong>₱ {item.price}</strong>
          </p>
          <Link to="" className="btn btn-primary">
            Add to Cart
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

The ProductPage is rendered by the following Route

```
<Route exact path="/Product-page/ProductPage/:productID" component={ProductPage} />
```

and the product fetch service is as follows

```
function getById(id) {  
      const requestOptions = { method: 'GET', headers: authHeader() }; 
      return fetch(Config.api.basepath+/product/+id,requestOptions)
            .then(handleResponse); 
}
```

and here`s my product page

```
componentDidMount() {
    let id = this.props.match.params.productID
    this.setState({
        id: id
    })

    }
```

Comment: I already call the id but how can i call the whole product data?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to fetch and display the product details based on id  on the product page

Assuming you are using react-hooks and implement ProductPage as a functional component, you can simply make use of useEffect hook to fetch the data

```
const ProductPage = ({ match }) => {
   const { params } = match;
   const { productID } = params;
   const [product, setProduct] = useState({isLoading: true, product {}});
   useEffect(() => {
        getyId(productId).then(product => setProduct({isLoading: false, product}));
  }, [productID]);

  if(product.isLoading) {
     return <Loader/>
  }
  return <div>{product.product.name}</div>
}
```

---

If you don't use react-hooks and implement a class component, you will have to use a combination of componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate lifecycle to fetch the product data

```
class ProductPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           isLoading: true,
           product: {}
       }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
       this.fetchProduct();
   }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if(prevProps.match.params.productID !== this.props.match.params.productID) {
           this.fetchProduct();
       }
    }

    fetchProduct() {
         this.setState({isLoading: true});
         getyId(productId).then(product => this.setState({isLoading: false, product}));
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading) {
         return <Loader/>
        }
        return <div>{this.state.product.name}</div> 
    }

}
```

Comment: sir im not using react hooks

Comment: Added a solution for class component too. I hope it will help you reach your final solution

Comment: where you get this     this.fetchProduct();  sir ?

Comment: @francebautista its a function defined in the class if you look inthe above post

Comment: so what im going to do is call my services to my productpage ?  right?  or nah

Comment: yes, you need to fetch the data by calling the service based on id on productpage

Comment: console.log(productService.getById()) i try this code in my product page and i got a response like this 


Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: You could define the state in a constructor. You maynot have setup webpack config to support the above state syntax. Also is possible only try to use the Logic for componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. The other things are for demonstration purpose

Comment: can you give sample ?

Comment: productService.getById().then(id => this.setState({ id }))

Comment: Seems correct. You need to check by exactly you receive from getById and then also ensure you have the state correctly set. In the above case if `id` is product, you would be setting the state by the name `id` and not product

Comment: the state is null and the componentdidmount always have a id, in this case  params = id and my state id = null. and also i always received this and i dont know how to fix it 


Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: @francebautista Please create a demo of you issue on codesandbox, I really an not sure what exactly is the problem you face

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-turing-nqpxk?file=/src/App.js

forget the output, look my code only sir thanks

Comment: I think you haven't saved your code. I cant see anything other than the template code on the link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-turing-nqpxk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: did you see now sir?

Comment: I cannot figure out the issue from it, There are jus so many things in there. the ProductPage component is supposed to be very simple